# Which version of "Barech alenu" to say on Shabas or yom tov?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, passover, mistakes, geshem-tal-ruach

We say the "*tal*" (dew) prayer at *musaf* on the first day of *Pesach*, inaugurating the season in which we no longer mention rain in the *amida* prayer. However, this is immediately relevant to only "*mashiv haruach umorid hagashem*" in the second benediction of the *amida*: the request for rain in the ninth benediction of the weekday *amida* is, well, only on weekdays, so its cessation is effective, practically, only after the first day(s) of *Pesach*, at the *maariv* prayer on the first day of *chol hamoed*.

In most people's versions of the ninth benediction, only a few words change in the middle depending on the season: the beginning of the benediction is constant.

If someone mistakenly starts to say the weekday *amida* at *mincha* on a holiday or *Shabas*, he is supposed to complete whatever benediction he finds himself amid, and then switch over to the holiday *amida*.

Suppose, then, someone mistakenly starts to say the weekday *amida* at *mincha* on the first day of *Pesach*, and catches himself after starting the ninth benediction. he should, of course, continue it. Should he recite the wintertime request for rain in it, perhaps because no one has yet begun the summertime version of the blessing, or should he not, perhaps because the summer prayer season's already been inaugurated?

Similarly:

We begin the ninth benediction's request for rain on a particular date in the fall. (This date varies by location.) Suppose the date falls on *Shabas*, and someone makes that same mistake: he says the weekday *amida* and catches himself after beginning the ninth benediction. Should he continue with the winter version, since the date for the switch has arrived, or with the summer version, since the community hasn't yet switched?

A sourced answer would be ideal.

Answer (score 2):

[*Kitzur Shulchan Aruch* 19:9](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%A8_%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%98#.28.D7.98.29) says:

> טעה במעריב ליל ראשון של פסח והתפלל תפלת שמונה עשרה של חול, ונזכר לאחר שהתחיל ברך עלינו שהדין הוא שצריך לסיים כל אותה ברכה (כמו שנתבאר לעיל סימן ע״ו) אינו אומר טל ומטר כיון שגם הציבור אינם אומרים. ואם חלה השאלה (הוא יום התחלת לשאול טל ומטר) ביום שבת וטעה והתפלל של חול והתחיל ברך עלינו גם כן אינו אומר טל ומטר כיוון שהציבור עדיין לא התחילו והיחיד נגרר תמיד אחר הציבור.‏
>
> If he erred at *maariv* the first night of *Pesach* and said the weekday *sh'mone esre* and remembered after he started [the ninth blessing,] "*Barech alenu*" …, he doesn't say "dew and rain", because the community, too, is not saying [it]. And if the day we start to request "dew and rain" comes out on *Shabas*, and he prayed a weekday [*sh'mone esre*] and started [the ninth blessing,] "*Barech alenu*", he, too, doesn't say "dew and rain", because the community hasn't yet started, and the individual is always dragged along with the community.

He doesn't say what to do at *mincha* the first day of *Pesach*.

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%96_%D7%90#.D7.91_.D7.91.D7.94.D7.9C Magen Avraham and Beiur Halakha too

Comment: Would prayers on Erev Pesach that falls on Shabbat have the same rule as Pesach night? According to the logic it seems they would