# המלך המשפט on Yom Tov

Tags: tefilla, shabbat, yom-kippur, mistakes, rosh-hashanah-new-year

According to [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/43530/11532), if you accidentally start the weekday shemoneh esrei on Shabbos Cheshvan 7/December 5 or the first day of Pesach, you don't say ותן טל ומטר because the rest of the community isn't saying it yet/anymore.

Does the same apply to המלך המשפט?  If you said המלך הקדוש correctly but then continued with the weekday shemoneh esrei on Rosh Hashana, Shabbos that immediately follows it, or Yom Kippur, and you realize in the middle of השיבה שפטינו, how do you end the bracha?

Comment: (Yes, this is a very unlikely scenario.)

Comment: I can't imagine why you wouldn't finish it המלך המשפט. There's no rule of waiting for the Chazzan/community to start like by rain requests as seen in formal Tefillat Geshem and such

Comment: @DoubleAA is there a formal start for ותן טל ומטר?  (I mean the gabbai usually announces it, but is that meakeiv like for mashiv haruach?)  And tefilat tal isn't a formal end for it either, since you end earlier according to the linked answer.

Comment: It's an interesting question and there is what to say about it (the Kalir for Geshem has both Mazkirei and Shoalei Matar), but that's getting more technical than necessary. Precipitation prayers have a communal element to them (נגרר אחר הציבור), unlike prayers related to calendar/holidays which is the case here. How exactly the communal element of precipitation prayers is expressed Halakhically can vary but is ultimately irrelevant to the conceptual difference which undermines your comparison